# How to get parameter of array in url path in get method in laravel API

Tags: laravel

If url is "http://example.com/api/test?p=1&p=2" and method is "GET", I want to get [1,2] when I trying to call $request->p  or $request->query("p").

But now, if url is same, I'll get "2" when I call $request->p.

How to do it?

Comment: Did you read the docs? These are laravel basics `$request->query('p')` will get the url parameter "p". You could have found that yourself...

Comment: @GertB. but $request->query('p') is also return "2", not [1,2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parameter can only hold one value. In `?p=1&p=2` the second `p=...` sets the value for the parameter, overwriting the first one. If you want two values your parameter should be an array like this:

```
?p[]=1&p[]=2
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what I want, and it work successfully.